# Please help me in this probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

We have  sequence of $n$ iid random variables each following gamma distribution with parameters $2$ and $1$. We want the probability that mean of $n$ such random variables is equals to $2$ as $n$ approaches infinity.

I have tried problem, but I think answer should be $1$ rather than $0$. Because the random variables follow gamma distribution with parameters $2$ and $1$. So the mean will be $2$. Hence, using the law of large numbers we can say that mean for the large $n$ will be equal to $1$ almost surely.

Am I doing it right? But the answer is $0$. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z = X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$ where each $X_i$ follows $\gamma(2,1)$

Then $Z$ follows $\gamma(2n,1)$ the mean of $Z$ then is $2n$.  The probability that Z will have a mean of 2 as n approaches infinity naturally is =$0$.

The question is a little bit absurd.

Comment: Sorry  i think, I asked about the probability of mean of N iid random variables rather than sum for which you provided. That is W = Z/n. Then, the mean of W will be 2, isn't.

Comment: Then it is what you said, mean of such a W will be 2. You are correct.  What I say absurd is the probability measure of whether it is 2 is what looks funny about it.

Comment: Then, probability that mean of such W would be equal to 2 for large n will be what? I am really confused in this. I think it should be 1 because it is certain that for large n the mean of W will approach 2. But the correct answer is 0.